# Read the data page wise and store in separate files

Tags: text-processing

I have a huge text file where data is separated pagewise. For example, the text is in below format and I want to read lines pagewise and store each page in separate files.

```
Page 1
 line 1
 line 2
 line 3
 line 4
 line 5
Page 2
 line 1
 line 2
 line 3
 line 4
 line 5
Page 3
 line 1
 line 2
 line 3
 line 4
 line 5
```

Comment: Please Edit your question and explain what you have tried so far and what your problem is within the scope of Linux/Unix.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution:**

```
awk '/^Page [0-9]+$/ {N = $2}; {print > "page"N}' pages
```

**Test run:**

```
==> page1 <==
 line 1
 line 2
 line 3
 line 4
 line 5

==> page2 <==
 line 1
 line 2
 line 3
 line 4
 line 5

==> page3 <==
 line 1
 line 2
 line 3
 line 4
 line 5
```

If there are thousands of pages though, with some `awk` implementations, you may run into the limit of number of open files. You can address that by closing the file for the previous page when finding the new page header. You may also want to 0-pad the numbers in the file names so that `ls` shows them in ascending order:

```
awk '
  /^Page [0-9]+$/ {close(file); file = sprintf("page%04d", $2)}
  {print > file}' pages
```

That assumes the input contains only one occurrence of `Page n` for each page.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution, ableit not as elegant as the `awk` one because it requires:

- knowing the number of lines per page
- this number has to remain constant across all pages

  ```
  split -l 6 -a 2 -d input page_
  ```

Here, 6 is the number of lines per page: 1 title line + 5 data lines

Answer (score 1):

Using `csplit`:

```
$ csplit -s -f page- file '/^Page/' '{1}'
$ ls
file    page-00 page-01 page-02
$ cat page-00
Page 2
 line 1
 line 2
 line 3
 line 4
 line 5
$ cat page-01
Page 2
 line 1
 line 2
 line 3
 line 4
 line 5
$ cat page-02
Page 3
 line 1
 line 2
 line 3
 line 4
 line 5
```

The `csplit` utility splits the given file according to its last arguments.  Here, `/^Page/` and `{1}` instructs `csplit` to split the file on the given regular expression, each time it's matching.  With GNU `csplit`, you would want to use `{*}` instead of `{1}` (the example above was written for OpenBSD `csplit`).

Answer (score -1):

command:

```
awk '$0 ~/Page 1/{f=1}$0 ~/Page 2/{f=0}f' o.txt > firstfile
 awk '$0 ~/Page 2/{f=1}$0 ~/Page 3/{f=0}f' o.txt > secondfile
awk '/Page 3/,/,/{print $0}' o.txt >thirdfile
```

output

```
een@praveen:~$ awk '$0 ~/Page 1/{f=1}$0 ~/Page 2/{f=0}f' o.txt > firstfile
Page 1
 line 1
 line 2
 line 3
 line 4
 line 5
praveen@praveen:~$ awk '$0 ~/Page 2/{f=1}$0 ~/Page 3/{f=0}f' o.txt > secondfile
Page 2
 line 1
 line 2
 line 3
 line 4
 line 5



awk '/Page 3/,/,/{print $0}' o.txt >thirdfile
Page 3
 line 1
 line 2
 line 3
 line 4
 line 5
praveen@praveen:
```

~$

Comment: The word "huge" in the question implies that there may well be more than three pages.